# During which part of the year does the Earth move toward the galactic centre?

Tags: astronomy, earth, celestial-mechanics, milky-way

The Earth orbits around the Sun which in turn orbits around the center of the Milky Way. In which part of the year is the Earth is moving away from the center of the Milky Way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The centre of the Milky Way is roughly in the direction of the constellation of Sagittarius, so Earth is furthest away when the Sun is in Sagittarius (November-December), and closest 6 months later.

Comment: Thanks dear @Anders, that was quick :-). I didn't figure it out that with the constelations one can roughly estimate the orientation.

Comment: The trick is knowing both a bit of astrology and a bit of astronomy :-)